# Add an area to the Line Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to plot a line chart where the X axes are the dates (see [this link](https://dudnic.com/covid-19)).

```js
var totalChartOptions = {
    chart : {title : 'Total cases'},
    curveType : 'function',
    legend : {position : 'none'},
    axes : {x : {0 : {side : 'top'}}},
    hAxis : {title : '', format : "dd/MM"},
    colors : [ 'orange', 'green', 'red' ],
    pointSize : 20,
    pointShape : 'diamond',
}

totalData.addColumn("date", "Date");
totalData.addColumn("number", "Confirmed");
totalData.addColumn("number", "Recovered");
totalData.addColumn("number", "Deaths");
... foreach (...)
        totalData.addRow([ date, confirmed, recovered, deaths, null ]);
... var chart = new google.charts.Line(totalElement);
chart.draw(totalData, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(vm.totalChartOptions));
```

For "today", I would like to add a colored area in order to show the data is not yet final.

[image].

However, I don't want the area be user-interactive(add another chart), just a specific background to the existing one. How do I do that?

Comment: will you please share the code used to draw the chart? it looks like you're using a _material_ line chart, which would make this much harder...

Comment: @WhiteHat I put the link in the OP, so the code you have ) yes, this is an material line chart

Comment: if you could, any relevant code should be posted here, for future reference and otherwise -- are you willing to use a classic chart? -- this would also mean a customization would be required for top x-axis...

Comment: I understand. Wondering what code should I put here knowing that these are material line chart?

Comment: for me personally, it is helpful to see the code that draws the chart, and a sample of the data so it can be re-created here. but you have a good point, I'm not sure how this could be accomplished with a material chart. with a classic chart, you can [use a combo chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720129/5090771) to draw the area. and I have this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60794486/5090771) that can manually move the x-axis to the top...

Comment: @WhiteHat is strange that Google put this beta vesion of material charts, totaly incomplete and unachieved, I even can't put point size or shape.... and the standard one does not support upper y axes... the low quality of the product and the complexity to work with takes me to move away from Google charts to Fusion or chartjs...

Answer (score 1):

*Material* charts do not support combo charts,
so it's not possible to mix line and area series'

there are also several config options that are not supported,
see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)...

and *Classic* charts do not have an option to present the x-axis on top.
however, we can manually modify the chart on the `'ready'` event.
to resolve, we use a *Classic* chart, and manually move the x-axis labels to the top.

using the `ComboChart`, we can add fourth series as an area.

```
totalData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
totalData.addColumn('number', 'Confirmed');
totalData.addColumn('number', 'Recovered');
totalData.addColumn('number', 'Deaths');
totalData.addColumn('number', 'Today');  // <-- area series
```

and add the following options, to set the main series type as line,
and change the fourth series to area.

```
seriesType: 'line',
series: {
  3: {
    type: 'area',
    color: 'yellow',
    pointSize: 0
  }
}
```

in order to display the area the full height of the chart area,
we need to find the max value displayed on the chart (or hard-code it).

```
// calculate y-axis range
var range = {
  min: null,
  max: null
};
for (var i = 1; i < totalData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  var colRange = totalData.getColumnRange(i);
  range.min = Math.min(range.min, colRange.min);
  range.max = Math.max(range.max, colRange.max);
}
```

and the area needs at least two row values,
in the following snippet, we use the row with today's date,
and add an additional day with otherwise, blank values.

```
// add area series data
var colIndex = totalData.getNumberOfColumns() - 1;
totalData.setValue(totalData.getNumberOfRows() - 2, colIndex, range.max);
totalData.setValue(totalData.getNumberOfRows() - 1, colIndex, range.max);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var totalData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  totalData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  totalData.addColumn('number', 'Confirmed');
  totalData.addColumn('number', 'Recovered');
  totalData.addColumn('number', 'Deaths');
  totalData.addColumn('number', 'Today');

  // simulate data
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 18), 1900, 0, 1, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 20), 1900, 0, 10, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 22), 4000, 2000, 100, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 24), 4000, 2000, 100, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 26), 2400, 0, 100, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 28), 3000, 1000, 110, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 2, 30), 4000, 1000, 90, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 3, 1), 4300, 5000, 20, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 3, 3), 0, 0, 0, null]);
  totalData.addRow([new Date(2020, 3, 4), null, null, null, null]);

  // calculate y-axis range
  var range = {
    min: null,
    max: null
  };
  for (var i = 1; i < totalData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    var colRange = totalData.getColumnRange(i);
    range.min = Math.min(range.min, colRange.min);
    range.max = Math.max(range.max, colRange.max);
  }

  // add area series data
  var colIndex = totalData.getNumberOfColumns() - 1;
  totalData.setValue(totalData.getNumberOfRows() - 2, colIndex, range.max);
  totalData.setValue(totalData.getNumberOfRows() - 1, colIndex, range.max);

  var totalChartOptions = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 60
    },
    title : 'Total cases',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {position : 'none'},
    hAxis: {title : '', format : 'dd/MM'},
    colors: ['orange', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'],
    pointSize: 20,
    pointShape: 'diamond',
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: range
    },
    seriesType: 'line',
    series: {
      3: {
        type: 'area',
        color: 'yellow',
        pointSize: 0
      }
    },
    theme: 'material'
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  // move x-axis to top
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
    var fontSize;
    var yCoord;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      fontSize = parseFloat(label.getAttribute('font-size'));
      switch (label.getAttribute('text-anchor')) {
        // chart title
        case 'start':
          yCoord = parseFloat(label.getAttribute('y'));
          label.setAttribute('y', yCoord - fontSize);
          break;

        // x-axis labels
        case 'middle':
          label.setAttribute('y', chartBounds.top - (fontSize / 2));
          break;

        // y-axis labels
        default:
          // ignore
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(totalData, totalChartOptions);
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: didn't though that this is so complicated to add a colored rectangle to the graph... more than that, you added data TILL the area, not IN the area... see what happens in that case: https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/VwLoMej?editors=1010